# Video to play on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am trying to get a video to play onclick of the video or even the wrapper around the video. I have multiple videos on the page. I have tried a few solutions including the script below but doesn't work.

```
    $('video').click(function(){
        this[this.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
    });
```

My HTML is

```
<div class="video">
    <video width="100%" height="100%">
        <source src="video/my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe something like `this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause()` but its just an idea

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use the div wrapper class instead of video element ? :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.video').click(function(){
           var myVideo = $(this).find("video")[0];
           myVideo.paused ? myVideo.play() : myVideo.pause()
      });
});
```

Here is a working example : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/MrGNeq

Comment: Hello, Yes but it still doesn't play :(

Comment: `$('video')` will target the video tag which will be needed to use `this.paused`. Changing the selector to `$('.video')` will target the `div` which isn't a player so no pause event/property will exist.

Comment: @AndréDS have you checked your answer? It doesn't work. `this.find("video")` => *"this.find is not a function"*. If you want to take this approach then you will need to change the variable selector `var myVideo = $(this).find("video")[0];` **Example:** [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3nbm7aL2/)

Comment: Solved + Example. It works. if it's ok for you, don't forget to mark your question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the video path? The possible reason for your issue can be following:

Your video is here: `http://<your-domain>/video/my-video.mp4`

You run you script on page: `http://<your-domain>/mypage`

In this case you video element looks for the video file here `http://<your-domain>/mypage/video/my-video`

The solution is to update your video element by specifying an absolute path to your video file:

```
<div class="video">
  <video width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="/video/my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="">
  </video>
</div>
```

In this case the video element will get video exactly from `http://<your-domain>/video/my-video.mp4`